# Configure Shiro context factory to connect to AD using Windows integrated security

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, shiro

I would like to avoid having a plain text password in the .ini file. I guess it should use Kerberos authentication, but I couldn't find how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Shiro has any capability to support Windows Kerberos authentication nor does it appear to have any "out of the box" capability to support encrypted passwords in the `[main]` section of the `shiro.ini` file.

Looking at this message (http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/How-to-secure-database-password-in-shiro-ini-td7578763.html) on the Shiro mailing list it suggests the best solution is to create your own password factory which will return the password when needed. The mailing list talks about using this for database passwords but the same principle should apply to Active Directory.

This link (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-445) contains a patch which should give you some pointers on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was trying to create my own context factory using Kerberos authentication following several approaches (not exclusive: SPNEGO, Waffle, JAAS...) but I didn't get it to work. I think I'll try to use some sort of key store for this.